# Given distinct events, with some mapping to the same ID, how can I find the most recent event for each ID and sum the results using Algebird?

Tags: scala, twitter, monoids, set-theory, algebird

I have been struggling for days to find a solution and so I'm hoping someone with more Algebird experience can help!

I have a stream of events I'm aggregating using Algebird, where each event represents an attempt to perform some task. Consider the following data structure to represent each attempt:

```
class TaskAttempt {
    val taskId: String
    val time: Int
    val type: String
    val value: Long
    val valueUnit: String
}
```

I am aggregating these attempts from a stream, and there is no guarantee that an attempt to perform a task will succeed. In the case that an attempt fails, I expect additional attempts for the same task. The aggregation I'm trying to build does the following:

1. Collect only the most recent attempt (based on the `TaskAttempt.time` field) for each task ID. Assume larger values for `TaskAttempt.time` mean the event happened more recently. All previous events for each task will be ignored.
2. Sum the `TaskAttempt.value` field from the `TaskAttempt` instances collected in step 1 into a `Map(type -> Map(valueUnit -> valueSum))`. This means that in the end, all values from each most recent task attempt will be summed if their `type` and `valueUnit` fields are equal.

I was hoping to accomplish the above using something like the following, but `.flatMap()` cannot be called on an Algebird `Preparer` after calling `.reduce()` because the latter returns a `MonoidAggregator` rather than a `Preparer`. Regardless, here is some non-working code to further show what I'd like to accomplish:

```
Preparer[NetworkAttemptSubmissionPrediction]
  // Aggregate attempts into Sets
  .flatMap { attempt =>
    for {
      a <- attempt
    } yield Set(a)
  }
  // Reduce by grouping TaskAttempt's by taskId and then collecting the
  // attempts with the largest value for time for each taskId
  .reduce {
    (
        l1: Set[TaskAttempt],
        l2: Set[TaskAttempt]
    ) =>
      (l1 ++ l2)
        .groupBy(_.taskId)
        .flatMap(entry: (String -> List[TaskAttempt]) => entry._2.maxBy(_.time))
        .toSet
  }
  // Map the remaining filtered attempts to the required Map
  .flatMap { attempt =>
    for {
      value <- attempt.value
    } yield Map(
      attempt.type -> Map(attempt.valueUnit -> value)
    )
  }
  .sum
```

Ultimately, I must provide the framework I'm using for the stream aggregation (internal tool built on top of Twitter's Summingbird) with a `MonoidAggregator[TaskAttempt, Map[String, Map[String, Long]], Map[String, Map[String, Long]]` that aggregates the data as described above. How can I accomplish this? Any other ideas for how I could make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I decided that rather than attempting to dedupe, I should avoid the need to dedupe altogether. I did this by adding additional "negative" task attempts to the topic which negate failed "positive" task attempts that come before them in the stream. By doing this, I can sum all of the events in the stream without worry of double counting due to the presence of multiple attempts for a single task.